# Compilation error

Tags: include

for the following code:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{report}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{setspace}
\usepackage{graphicx}

\include{\frontmatter/title}
\include{\frontmatter/abstract}
\include{\frontmatter/declaration}
\include{\frontmatter/quotation}
\include{\frontmatter/acknowledgements}

\end{document}
```

I get this error:

```
main.tex, line 7
Undefined control sequence.
<write> \string \@input {\frontmatter /title.aux}
l.7 \include{\frontmatter/title}

The control sequence at the end of the top line
of your error message was never \def'ed. If you have
misspelled it (e.g., `\hobx'), type `I' and the correct
spelling (e.g., `I\hbox'). Otherwise just continue,
and I'll forget about whatever was undefined.
```

Comment: `\frontmatter` is a command with special meanings. It's not designed to hold an input path. Either you have changed the meaning of `\frontmatter` (can't be seen here) or it's an error. Do you mean `\include{/frontmatter/title}`?

Comment: Thanks for your reply, I am trying to compile my thesis. so, I put files such as (title, abstract, abbreviations...etc) in a older labeled front matter. I use \include command to compile such files but I get the error message cited in my original question above. Do you mean changing the name of the 'frontmatter' folder will solve the problem?

Comment: Give it a try, but there might be other errors

Comment: I changed the name and got the error message of "Can be used only in the Preamble" Any suggestions please?

Comment: You have no `\begin{document}` before `\include...` stuff in your example above;-)

Comment: yes, I have: this is my code: %======================================Preamble=======================
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{report}

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage[left=2cm,right=2cm,top=2cm,bottom=2cm]{geometry}

%=======================front matter=================================

\begin{document}

\include{Yad/title}
\include{Yad/abstract}
\include{Yad/declaration}
\include{Yad/acknowledgement}
\include{Yad/abbreviations}


\end{document}

Comment: And now? What's inside of those various included files?

Comment: LATEX documents including abstract, title page, ..etc.. each one of them is a document class article.

Comment: You can't include another `\documentclass{article}..` with `\include` into another document, at least not this way. Please have a look on the `combine` package, but even more important: Have a look into some introductory LaTeX book ;-)

Answer (score 3):

The O.P. used `\include` with another full document, i.e. with `\documentclass` and full preamble inside a `\include{foo}` statement.

This can't work, at least not this way. For special purposes the `combine` package can be used.

Furthermore, in `\include`d files, no `\chapter` etc. should occur.

Since no more information is given no other suggestion than to read an introcuctory LaTeX book can be made. The O.P. never returned for precisely have half an year now.